# About F# function

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

Following is the function, which I wrote in F# editor and it works as I expected (answer:18).

```
let quadruple x = x*2
let cal(u:int) = quadruple u + 10;
let result = cal 4
```

But if I change the order of code, such as

```
let cal(u:int) = quadruple u + 10;
let quadruple x = x*2
let result = cal 4
```

I am getting "the value or constructor 'quadrule' not defined". From the error, I presume, the failure is due to a function call before its declaration. For me, it something like an interpreter style.

**Question:** Why such constrains ? Is this purposeful to keep some compatibility issue ? Or is it because I don't have any module/class defined ?

Comment: In F#, both compilation and definition order **matters**. I don't know what the reason for that is (probably type inference wouldn't work without it, or would work poorly), but the functions/modules have to be defined 'above' any other functions and/or modules using them. Same goes for full files that have to be moved 'up' above other files that might be referencing them.

Comment: @Nair: Having your dependencies modeled in code and by the structure of your project is a good thing. In C# it's much harder to manage interdependencies, especially with larger projects.

Comment: @Daniel, I presume, you mean F#

Comment: No, I mean in C#, which doesn't enforce dependency order, it's much harder to keep track. I consider F#'s approach an improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the minimal amount of type declarations required in idiomatic code, F# is a statically strongly typed language. This is possible because of compiler ability to infer types where it can be done **unambiguously** thru the process known as [type inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233180.aspx).

Simplistically, the processing direction that type inference works in F# is one pass top down left to right over the code. This factor affects both intra- and inter-file placement of definitions and usage of F# code elements.

Applying this principle to your second snippet: when compiler first comes over `quadruple` in the first line there is nothing known about the type of this element based on information parsed so far that would allow to disambiguat it; that's what the error message communicates.

**Note:** there is a certain deviation from this principle in the area of F# related to OOP, where usage before definition is allowed to some extent, like for `Code` property usage in a `Sample` class method `Double()` below, where it is used prior to the property definition:

```
type Sample() =
    member this.Double() = this.Code * 2
    member this.Code with get() : int = 3
```

For the fine-grain details upon type inference workings the best place to check is [F# Language Specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html).